# After installing JetPack, can I delete the WordPress stats plugin?

Tags: plugins, plugin-jetpack

After running the WordPress stats plugin for many years, I've decided to upgrade to JetPack. The installation went smoothly, I connected and authorized my blog with Wordpress.com, and I'm seeing stats.

Is it safe to deactivate and delete my old WordPress stats plugin now? Or do I need to keep it in order to preserve my historical data?

I'm a bit shocked that WordPress hasn't provided a step-by-step upgrade guide for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can safely deactivate the old wordpress.com stats Plugin. Once you verify that your historical data have been retained, you can safely delete the Plugin.